# Unable to create material design (mdi) checkbox in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, material-design-icons

In my application I'm using material design icons. I load them like so:

```
<link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.5.94/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It works good in many parts of the application, but it does not work with checkboxes. This is how I create checkboxes in one of my methods:

```
return this.$createElement(VCheckbox, {

});
```

I do not get any error messages, but instead of checkboxes I see some text, when page is rendered:

[image]

I inspected the DOM and see this:

```
<div class="v-input__slot">
    <div class="v-input--selection-controls__input">
        <input aria-checked="false" role="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="">
        <div class="v-input--selection-controls__ripple"></div>
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light">check_box_outline_blank</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I see that instead of `mdi` theme `material-icons` theme is applied. I do not know how to fix it. What I want to get, is to have `mdi-checkbox-marked-outline` class for checked checkboxes and `mdi-checkbox-blank-outline` for unchecked.

Comment: Are you sure you need a render function? What about just writing  <v-checkbox /> in your template?